# Append content to a document

Tags: apex, batch, governorlimits

I need to create a huge document.
Naturally I face up the apex's limits such that heap size and string length.
I can split the creation of the document using a batch job. I thought to create the rows of this big document inside the execute method of the batch job and then write down **only the new rows** of the document avoiding the apex limits.

However this is useless because I always need to retrieve the document, retrieve its body append the new rows of the current execution and update the document.

```
global class exportContactsCampaigns implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,  List<Contact> contactList){

        // create the rows for this execution
        String sExport = oExportHelper.buildExportString(contactList);

        // finished to elaborate the records, let's free some heap memory.
        contactList.clear();

        // update the document
        Document d = [SELECT Id, Body from document where Id = '01511000000OcXR'];
        String sCurrentBody = d.Body.toString();
        sCurrentBody += sExport; // PROBLEM!!! HEAP LIMIT OVERFLOW OR STRING LENGTH OVERFLOW
        d.Body = Blob.valueOf(sCurrentBody);
        update d;
    }
}
```

So my question is:
*Is there a way to append the rows to a document without retrieving it's body?*

Comment: Why do you need to create this document in Apex? (You'd be better off doing it almost anywhere else, and retrieving the data from SFDC using API calls.)

Comment: I have million of records to analyze, so I prefer doing it inside salesforce without the overhead of get all these data with api.

Comment: @lastYorsh Did you find any solution or work around for this? I am having a similar requirement and have no clue how to achieve this.

Comment: @SaumyaRanjanSatapathy: at the end I've managed with a workaround. I've created an external web service using some simple php code. At the end of each batch job I call that web service with the records exported. The web service appends the exported record in a file stored in a remote server, out from salesforce. I know, It is a really complex solution, but it was the only one I've found.